# Try to install a powerpoint´s add in with powershell script

Tags: powershell, powerpoint, add-in

I made an add in for powerpoint and I found a script for powershell to install. This is the script:

```
[CmdletBinding()]
Param(
    [Parameter(Position=0,Mandatory=$true)]
        [String]$AddinPath,
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$false)]
        [Switch]$Reinstall,
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$false)]
        [Switch]$NoCopy
)

# Ensure that any errors we receive are considered fatal
$ErrorActionPreference = 'Stop'

# The path to the default folder to copy Excel add-ins
$ExcelAddinsPath = Join-Path $env:APPDATA 'Microsoft\AddIns'

if (Test-Path -Path $AddinPath -PathType Leaf) {
    $Addin = Get-ChildItem -Path $AddinPath
    if ($Addin.Extension -NotIn ('.ppam')) {
        Write-Error 'The file does not appear to be a Power Point add-in.'
    }
} else {
    Write-Error 'The add-in file path does not appear to be valid.'
}

try {
    Add-type -AssemblyName office
    $Application = New-Object -ComObject powerpoint.application
    $Application.visible = [Microsoft.Office.Core.MsoTriState]::msoTrue
    $slideType = "microsoft.office.interop.powerpoint.ppSlideLayout" -as [type]

    $blanklayout = $slideType::ppLayoutTitleOnly

    $presentation = $application.Presentations.add()

    $slide = $Presentation.Slides.Add($presentation.Slides.Count + 1, 15)
} catch {
    Write-Error 'Microsoft Excel does not appear to be installed.'
}

try {

    $PowerPointAddins = $Application.Addins

    $AddinInstalled = $PowerPointAddins | ? { $_.Name -eq $Addin.Name }


    if (!$AddinInstalled -or $Reinstall) {
        if (!(Test-Path -Path $ExcelAddinsPath -PathType Container)) {
            New-Item -Path $ExcelAddinsPath -ItemType Directory  
        }

        if (!$NoCopy) {
            Copy-Item -Path $Addin.FullName -Destination $ExcelAddinsPath -Force
            $Addin = Get-ChildItem -Path (Join-Path $ExcelAddinsPath $Addin.Name)
            $Addin.IsReadOnly = $true
        }
        
     
        $NewAddin = $presentation.Application.AddIns.Add('C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\AddIns\AddinthatIcreated.ppam', $true)
        $NewAddin.Installed = $true
        Write-Host ('Add-in "' + $Addin.BaseName + '" successfully installed!')
    } else {
        Write-Host ('Add-in "' + $Addin.BaseName + '" already installed!')
    }
} finally {
    $Application.Quit()
}
```

This script take the .ppam file and put in the AddinFile, but appear an error and this message:

**Cannot find an overload for "Add" and the argument count: "2"**

this message appears when the script execute this instrucction (Line 60):

```
$NewAddin = $presentation.Application.AddIns.Add('C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\AddIns\AddinthatIcreated.ppam', $true)
```

what is the source of the problem and how Can I solve it? Thanks for help me!

Comment: Where did you get the script? According to the docs, [AddIns.Add](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/powerpoint.addins.add) has one parameter only.

Comment: I took from this page https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/PSWinGlue/0.3.1/Content/Scripts%5CInstall-ExcelAddin.ps1 but the problem is that this script is for Excel addin

Comment: As above - it only takes a single argument. Try removing `,$true` from that line, though it may not work anyway you;d have to check the whole script works for Powerpoint rather than Excel methods.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is caused by mixing up Excel and PowerPoint methods. Although the names are the same, the function prototypes are not. One can find the acceptable versions by googling `excel addins.add` and `powerpoint addins.add`, which will provide hits on Microsoft's documentation pages.

For Powerpoint, the `AddIns.Add()` method [takes a single parameter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/powerpoint.addins.add), file name.

For Excel, the `AddIns.Add()` method [takes two parameters](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.addins.add), file name and copy file.

As resolution, change the call to have just single parameter like so,

```
$NewAddin = $presentation.Application.AddIns.Add('C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\AddIns\AddinthatIcreated.ppam')
```